# Inconsistent results moving row from sheet to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following code executes inconsistently.  Sometimes it does what it's supposed to do - move one row from one tab/page/sheet to another.  Other times - it moves TWO rows.  I'm perplexed as to what I could be doing wrong.  Any ideas?  I suspect there's a google bug, but how can I validate it one way or the other?

I apologize if this isn't the right place to ask for help of this kind and if it's not, then please point me to the proper place.

Thank you in advance.

My file containing onEdit() trigger:

```
var LIBRARY_VERSION=1.61

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function happyFunTime(e) {
//Logger.log(getCachedUser("happyFunTime at the top"));
  var duplicate=0;
  var msg;
  var debug=true;

  if (debug)
    Logger.log("Inside happyFunTime()");

  duplicate=checkNewEntryForDuplicate(e);
  if (debug)
    Logger.log("duplicate=" + duplicate);

  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = sourceSheet.getActiveCell();
  var columnNum = r.getColumn();
  var notesColumnOffset = getNotesColumnOffset();
  var rowNum = r.getRow();
  var sourceSheetName=sourceSheet.getName();

  if (rowNum <=1) {
    Logger.log("rowNum = " + rowNum + " Exiting happyFunTime() at  line 30");
    return;
  }


  if (duplicate) {

    if (debug)
      Logger.log("Duplicate.  Exiting happyFunTime() at  line 38");
    return;
  }

  notesColumnOffset++;
  // set dateCell = the current row at column J
  var notesCell = sourceSheet.getRange(rowNum, notesColumnOffset);
  var tZone="America/Los_Angeles";

  // Format the current date into datetime format
  var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tZone, "MMM-dd-yyyy h:mm a");


  // set row color as soon as we know the status
  var outCome=setRowColor(rowNum);  
  if (!duplicate) {
    var targetSheetName=outCome[0];    

   if (debug) {
     msg="happyFunTime(): Library_Version: " + LIBRARY_VERSION + " Calling getUserName()"
     myLog(msg);
   }
   var user=getUserName("happyFunTime()"); 


    if (debug) {
      msg="happyFunTime(): Back from Calling getUserName().  Library_Version:"  + LIBRARY_VERSION;
      myLog(msg);
      msg=("happyFunTime(): I am " + user);
      myLog(msg);
    }
    var comment=dateTime + "\nLast Edited By: " + user;

    if (debug) {
      msg=("happyFunTime(): comment= " + comment);
      myLog(msg);
    }
    notesCell.setComment(comment);


    // check to see if sourceSheetName is the same as targetSheetName and if so, do not moveRow.
    if (targetSheetName != sourceSheetName) {
      if (debug)
        Logger.log("happyFunTime(): Getting targetSheetName=" + targetSheetName);
      var obj;
      // if sheet exists
      obj=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(targetSheetName);


      if (obj) {
        if (debug)
          Logger.log("happyFunTime(): Calling moveRow()");
       moveRow(sourceSheetName, targetSheetName, rowNum);

      }
  } // if (targetSheetName != sourceSheetName)
} // if (!duplicate)
if (debug)
    Logger.log("Leaving happyFunTime()");
}

    function moveRow(sourceSheetName, targetSheetName, sourceRowNum) {
    var debug=true;

    if (debug)
      Logger.log("Inside libFuncs.gs: moveRow()");


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);  
    var sourceSheet=ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
    var sourceRange;
    var msg;

      if (targetSheet == null) return;

      var targetRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
      var maxRows=targetSheet.getMaxRows(); //  for debugging


      if (targetRow > targetSheet.getMaxRows())
        targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetRow - 1);

      if (debug) {
        msg = "targetSheetName=" + targetSheetName + "  rowNum=" + sourceRowNum;
        Logger.log(msg);
       }
        sourceRange=sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRowNum, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, 1));
        sourceSheet.deleteRow(sourceRowNum);

    if (debug)
      Logger.log("Leaving libFuncs.gs: moveRow()");    

    }
```

Here is the execution transcript for a broken run:

```
[14-02-18 15:28:49:898 PST] Logger.log([happyFunTime(): Calling moveRow(), []]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:49:898 PST] Logger.log([Inside libFuncs.gs: moveRow(), []]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:49:899 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:50:374 PST] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([VM]) [0.475 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:50:616 PST] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Leads]) [0.242 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:50:640 PST] Sheet.getLastRow() [0.022 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:50:866 PST] Sheet.getMaxRows() [0.225 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:50:904 PST] Sheet.getMaxRows() [0.035 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:50:904 PST] Logger.log([targetSheetName=VM  rowNum=6, []]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:51:122 PST] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0.217 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:51:122 PST] Sheet.getRange([6, 1, 1, 16]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:51:123 PST] Sheet.getRange([93, 1]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:51:873 PST] Range.toString() [0 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:51:873 PST] Range.copyTo([Range]) [0.749 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:52:131 PST] Sheet.deleteRow([6]) [0.257 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:52:132 PST] Logger.log([Leaving libFuncs.gs: moveRow(), []]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:52:132 PST] Logger.log([Leaving happyFunTime(), []]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-18 15:28:52:134 PST] Execution succeeded [11.968 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: weird... I also belive there is a bug somewhere

Comment: When you say it copies 2 rows, what is the content of these rows?

Comment: I suspect you're not asking for the actual data, but whether or not the rows differ from each other?  They do differ.  Each row contains maybe 16 columns.  Row 1 might contain say "Elm Street" and row 2 might contain "Oak Street".  While only row 1 should be moved to a different sheet, both row 1 & row 2 move.  Each row is intact after moving... except that row 2 shouldn't have moved at all.  Is that what you're asking?  Or did you want actual specific row data?

Comment: Here is the execution transcript for a broken run:

Comment: What triggers moveRow() in the 1st place? Are you pressing a Ui button (possibly twice?), submitting a form, running onEdit, or clicking a custom menu ...?

Comment: it's an onEdit trigger.

Comment: @Bryan I added the trigger code above.